# Relations. Are these sets reflexive, transitive, symmetric, etc.?

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

I'm studying relations at the moment, but I can't solve this problem. Could you please give me a piece of advice? I really want to understand how to solve it. Thank you in advance!

> Let R be a relation on a nonepty set X. Is this relation reflexive,
> transitive, symmetric, antisymmetric? Is it equivalence relation,
> partial order, total order? If it's an equivalence relation, identify
> the equivalence classes.
>
> 1. X = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}, R = {(a,b)| a + b is even number},
> 2. X = $\mathbb R^2$, R = "symmetric with respect to x-axis",
> 3. X =$\mathbb R^2$, R = "is at the same distance form origin",
> 4. X = {all human beings}, R = "to be brother",
> 5. X = {all human beings}, R = "live in the same city".

Here are my thoughts on this so far (I may be really wrong, but anyway):

1. Reflexive and symmetric.
2. Symmetric.
3. Reflexive and symmetric.
4. Antisymmetric?
5. Also antisymmetric?

Answer (score 0):

5) is symmetric (if x lives in same city as y, then y lives in same city as x).

5) is also reflexive (x lives in same city as x), but 4 is not (no one is brother of themselves .. so 4 is in fact irreflexive).

4) is not antisymmetric: x and y can be brothers of each other. Also not symmetric (x can be brother of y, but y can be sister of x)

Any thoughts on transitivity for these?

Comment: Thank you so much! I guess I see it now... As for transitivity, I'm almost sure that 4th can't be transitive.

Comment: @user497449 .. and why not? What's your explanation?

Comment: I was thinking...  If x is related to y and y is related to z, then x is related to z, right? But if the relation is "to be brother", it doesn't have to be true, because x and z may not be siblings. I'm not sure if it's correct though.

Comment: @user497449 well, if x is brother of y, and y brother of z ... then x is definitely male, and so it *seems* as if x would be brother of z (also because we don;t care about gender of z) .. But here is the thing: x and z could be the same person!

Comment: Oh, I get it! Thank you for explanation!!

Comment: Also, you need to know whether full brother (both parents the same) or half brother (one common parent) is meant.  Transitivity fails for half brother for a reason in addition to that user497449 mentions .

Comment: @user497449 OK, and what about transitivity of the others?

Comment: @Bram28 The 5th one seems to be an equivalence relation. Reflexive, because we know that x lives in that city. Also symmetric, because if x and y live in the city, nothing changes if we rearrange them. And transitive, because if x and y live in the same city and x and z live in the same city, then x an z also live in the same city. I hope I understood it in the right way.

Comment: The first one has to be transitive. For example, if we have 1+3=4 and 3+5=8, both numbers are even, then 1+5=6, and 6 is even. I don't really understand how to think about transitivity in terms of R^2 (problems 2,3) though. :(

Comment: @user497449 Agreed on 1.  3. shouldn't be hard either: if x is  as far away from origin as y, then they are equally far away, And so if y is also equally far away as z is, then x is just as far away as z is. So 3 is transitive. In fact, 3 is an equivalence relation: you can often recognize these when they have some kind of 'equality' in their definition; in this case equidistance. For 2, remember why 4 was not transitive.

Answer (score 0):

a and b live in the same city when there is some city in which both a and b live.

Joe is a farmer who lives on his farm outside of any city.
Joe is in X.  There is no city in which both Joe and Joe live.

Thus 5 is not an equivalence relation because it is not reflexive.